# Inner div not taking the whole scroll width of outer div

Tags: html, css

I have a sample using html and CSS at following link: https://js.do/sun21170/inner-width-not-taking-whole-of-outer-width

The problem is that the inner div with a greenish background color is not taking the whole scroll width of outer div.

**Question** : Is there some CSS that I can use to make the inner div style apply across the whole scroll width of outer div other than setting the width of inner div to something like 150% or so?

Sample code that I am using is as below.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div  
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.outerDiv {
   max-width:500px;
   border:2px solid purple;
   overflow:auto;
   height: 100px;
}
.innerDiv {
   border:1px dashed red;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   white-space:nowrap;
   width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply set the `.innerDiv` to `display: inline-block;`. This way, the `.innerDiv` behaves like an inline element, which is always as wide as its content, if you don't specify a `width`.

Here is the working example:

```css
.outerDiv {
   max-width:500px;
   border:2px solid purple;
   overflow:auto;
   height: 100px;
}
.innerDiv {
   display: inline-block; /* ← this does the trick */
   border:1px dashed red;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   white-space:nowrap;
   /* width: 100%; ← this has to be removed */
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :) Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to see the simple solution :D

Comment: One issue. Please have a look at a similar sample at https://js.do/sun21170/inner-width-not-taking-whole-of-outer-width-copy, which has now 2 inner divs instead of 1. The inner divs are not spanning the whole outer scroll width even though I have used your recommended CSS for display inline-block.

Comment: You have to remove the `width:100%;` rule (otherwise, your inner divs will always be as wide as the visible part). Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried removing the `width:100%`, but then second inner div takes a smaller width than the first inner div. I was expecting the inner div to span the whole scroll width.

Comment: Have you updated your js.do link? I can't see a second inner div. And yes, that would be the expected result for inline level elements. If you want to have them all have the same `width` you'll have to declare fixed width for them...

Comment: Sorry, yes I may have changed it but its back to two inner divs.

Comment: Ok, in this case, you have to set a min width, e.g. `min-width: 160%;`. This would make all inline elements equal width, if their own width is smaller. The downside is, you would have to know the length of the widest inline element...

Answer (score 1):

<s>Well, you can do as @andreas suggested above:~~</s>

- Add `display: inline-block` to `.innerDiv`
- Remove `width: 100%` from `.innerDiv`

Or... If you want to avoid that overflow effect, you can remove `white-space: nowrap` from your `.innerDiv` class!

**One question;** When you have 2 `.innerDiv` do you want them to stack below each other? If so, do you want both of them to have a stretched background to the end of the `.outerDiv`?

**EDIT:** Your problem wasn't clear enough for me at the beginning, but now I've understood what you really need to achieve, and here are 2 solutions:

## #1 Solution: `table-row`

```css
.outerDiv {
   max-width:500px;
   border:2px solid purple;
   overflow:auto;
   height: 100px;
}
.innerDiv {
   display: table-row; /* <-- Add this */
   border:1px dashed red;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div  
    </div>
     <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div   
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## #2 Solution: `Relative & Absolute` position!

**NOTE:** This can be used without `position: relative` and `position: absolute`, just use `display: inline-block` in `.wrapperDiv` and it will be the same!

```css
.outerDiv {
   position: relative; /* <-- Add this */
   max-width:500px;
   border:2px solid purple;
   overflow:auto;
   height: 100px;
}
.wrapperDiv { 
   position: absolute; /* <-- Add this */
}
.innerDiv {
   border:1px dashed red;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
   <div class="wrapperDiv"> <!-- Add This -->
    <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div  
    </div>
     <div class="innerDiv">
      This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div   
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Yes the inner divs will be stretched to whole scroll width of outer div. Also, the inner divs could have different background colors.

Comment: I need the inner div contents to not wrap.

Comment: thanks. Solution 1 is an excellent solution and it works in my case.

Comment: You're welcome @Sunil

If that what you was looking for, marked it as the Best Answer will give it more visibility to anyone who is facing the same problem. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flex box for the outer container by adding this:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
```

Working example:

```css
.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.innerDiv {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.innerDiv2 {
  background-color: lightpink;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv2">
    This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div This is inner div
  </div>
</div>
```